# Is using memcpy to construct a trivially copyable union UB? Active member?

Tags: c++, initialization, undefined-behavior, memcpy, unions

I'm worried about undefined behavior. Can you initialize the value of a trivially copyable union type by using a memcpy? This came up when I considered using Boost Serialization with [`BOOST_IS_BITWISE_SERIALIZABLE(MyUnionType)`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/libs/serialization/doc/traits.html#bitwise), which I assume uses something like memcpy.

```c++
#include <cstring>

enum class Foo: int {};

union Bar {
    int num;
    Foo foo;
};

int baz(int src) {
    Bar dst;

    // My understanding is that memcpy does initialize dst
    // but doesn't set the active member of the union.
    std::memcpy(&dst, &src, sizeof(Bar));

    // My understanding is that whichever member is read
    // first here becomes the active member of the union.
    if (src > 42) {
        return dst.num;
    } else {
        return (int)dst.foo;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see an issue with this case, from definition:

**A trivially copyable class is a class (defined with class, struct or union) that:**

- uses the implicitly defined copy and move constructors, copy and move assignments, and destructor.
- has no virtual members.
- its base class and non-static data members (if any) are themselves also trivially copyable types.

**Member lifetime**
The lifetime of a union member begins when the member is made active. If another member was active previously, its lifetime ends.

Foo in this case is itself trivially copyable

```
static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable_v<Bar>);
```

So I don't see any reason for UB

Comment: What makes me wary is that I think you're only allowed to read the active member of the union, which generally is the last member that was written to. But since memcpy doesn't specify any member, there can't be an active member at that point. That's why I suppose the active member would have to be determined by whichever member is read from (or written to) first after the memcpy. I don't see that mentioned in the [standard](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.union) though.

Comment: I see your worries, from the c++17 standard *For any object (other than a base-class subobject) of trivially copyable type T, whether or not the object
holds a valid value of type T, the underlying bytes (6.6.1) making up the object can be copied into an array of char, unsigned char, or std::byte (21.2.1).39 If the content of that array is copied back into the object, the object shall subsequently hold its original value* . This means that copying a union will preserve it's state and you are fine. What memcpy into a union member does isn't defined as far as I can tell